# VB.Net Streamwriting/Reading Text File to Tab Delimited

Tags: vb.net, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm relatively new to vb.net and am working on an entry-level project for my new job. I've spent a couple of days looking to get the hang of Streamwriter and Streamreader, which I haven't used anything like with any other programming language I've used, and could use a little advice.

I need to open a text file, remove unnecessary characters (such as quotes), and remove spaces between (but not within) entries, ultimately creating a tab-delimited text file.

It seems simple enough, conceptually, but something just isn't clicking for me. What I need to do is:

1. Establish the point in the initial document where I will begin reading from, or, if it would be more simple, where I will begin writing from.
2. Come up with the most effective and efficient way to read established lengths of entered data, trim them, then copy them over, appending a Tab.
3. Moving on to the next line, which will be formatted differently, and repeating step 2, adapted to this new line.
4. Every record in the primary document will be a collection of 5-7 lines, each formatted different, and then it will move on to another record, possibly necessitating a Loop, I would think.
5. Terminating the program when it reaches the end of the initial document.

Like I said, I'm sure this is sleepy-time-child's-play once any kind of experience is under the belt, but I don't have any with Streamwriter or Streamreader.

Any help from the stackoverflow community would be invaluable. Thanks for your time.

Comment: So you want to convert an existing CSV file into a tab delimited one? Please confirm. +1 for sensible wording.

Comment: I'm actually not certain if it qualifies as a CSV or not. It's more like a...text-based screencap of their records. Heh...how's that for sensible wording? It's the best way I can describe it, though. The entry fields each have established lengths, with not all of them filling it completely. Some tabs, some spaces...just a big sloppy text file.

At this point I can get it to remove the quotes and to actually give me *almost* the output I need. I just need a reliable way to remove some lines, too. Headings, breakers, and the like. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please include a sample of your input. It may not look exactly like a CSV, but it may conform to CSV standards, which you can use in your advantage. Reliable way of doing it is what I am trying to boil down to. Sensible = means something that makes sense. Your explanation makes sense, and is well versed, this is rare on StackOverflow these days, especially to expect from new users. Hence, a +1.

Comment: Well...it actually seems like I may have figured the ins and outs of the Streamwrite and Streamread, though now I'm worried about some serious code bloat.

However, that's a whole other bucket of worms. I *think* what I was going for here may actually be resolved. I really appreciate the attention and offered assistance, Neo. If I think the next phases of this project are ones I need help with, I'll be sure to put more about it up on here. For now, though, I think I'll try to work through it as best I can. :)

Thanks again!

Comment: No offense, but you may have only considered the tip of the iceberg. People who approach parsing CSV usually say "oh it's just one line of code `split(,)` - done. Well it turns out that to handle all possible scenarios, make it solid and perform fast, a library has to be created. I had to work a lot with CSVs at my previous job, so that's why you may find me biased to suggest use of a 3rd party CSV parser (there are many free ones out there), it will save you a lot of effort **in the long run**.

Comment: I'll definitely keep that in mind, Neo. For now, this is a kind of...'practice' exercise for the new job. I'm not entirely certain how much of this particular task I'll be doing or redoing, but I'll most certainly remember your advice if it comes down to a lot of parsing. Thanks again. I really appreciate it.